# How to Deploy a particular module in nopcommerce?

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am new to nopcommerce and i have created one simple module in nopcommerce store.

Now, i want to deploy that particular module so that i can install it on another machine and can bind it with a nopcommerce store running on another machine.

But, i don't find any help that how to deploy it and makes its setup of package so that i can install it in another machine.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance..

All answers are expected.

Answer (score 1):

To add your *plugin* to another store you should

1. build the plugin
2. find it in the Nop.Web/Plugins
3. сopy the folder with all DLLs of your plugin
4. paste this folder in the other store in the Nop.Web/Plugins

Before running the *Prepare.bat* and *Deploy.bat* you should add the plugin in the build/nop.plugins.targets

Note: Prepare.bat is optional, Deploy.bat calls Prepare.bat and runs the remaining Deploy.bat code at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To make a easy deploy you must run two bat's. **Prepare.bat** and **Deploy.bat**.

After it, you take Installed folder and upload into a FTP server.

http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/17891/why-use-preparebat-deploybat.aspx